# What is the "Printing Administration Tool"?

Tags: arch-linux, printing

I am trying to troubleshoot my CUPS printing system using system-config-printer. When I run the troubleshooting tool I get the following message:

[image]

This message refers to a "printing administration tool". What is this tool? There is no "System" choice in the system-config-printer menu. Is this some reference to the Gnome desktop or something? I do not use Gnome.

Comment: I suspect they may be referring to gnome-cups-manager, which as you have probably surmised comes with GNOME.

Answer (score 2):

The option "Publish shared printers connected to this system" refers to an option in the `Server` -> `Settings...` dialog of `system-config-printer`:

[image]

It changes the following settings in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` (on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen localhost:631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
# Disable printer sharing.
Browsing Off
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  # Restrict access to the server...
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
```

to

```
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
# Share local printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  # Allow shared printing...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>
```

when enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, cups admin is done in the browser. Try web page `http://localhost:631/`.  This is enabled by `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` in the line `WebInterface Yes`, and `Port 631`. See `man cupsd.conf`.